# how to remove the default img in the select option?

Tags: html, css

[image]

is there a way to make the select options like the above? how to remove the default img in the select options? thank you.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question! Ive been searching for the solution for this along time. My belief is that, this is the bestest solution:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/
You use it with jQuery UI and fully edit with css. However even more better solution would be making fully div and li based dropdown-menu with a hidden input, if you want to use it in a form.

Answer (score 2):

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/

This is a really good tutorial from a reliable site :)

I'm aware it uses jQuery but also makes use of CSS3